# Get EntityKey without loading referenced Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

is it possible to get entity key from EntityReference property without loading it?

I tried:

```
entity.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value
```

But if referenced entity isn't loaded by EntityReference.Load() method, EntityKey property is null.

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF 4, use FK associations instead of independent associations if you want this feature.

For EF 1, `EntityKey` will be `null` if the `query.MergeOption` is `MergeOption.NoTracking`.

Comment: Thanks, MergeOption was set to NoTracking.